# Jetpack Compose tests are failed if there is "Visible.Gone" element

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, testing, android-jetpack-compose

Compose elements that have `android::visibility="gone"` (In the XML) are failed the tests.
this is the error that I get:

```
Wait for [Compose-Espresso link] to become idle timed out
```

This is the XML ekement:

```
 <***.****.designsystem.wrapper.MainActionViewButton
                android:id="@+id/complete_btn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseline"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/baseline"
                android::visibility="gone"
                app:buttonText="@{@string/complete_job}"
                app:iconDrawable="@drawable/ic_complete_btn_icon"
                app:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onCompleteButtonClick()}" />
```

and this is the test file:

```
        @SmallTest
        class CompleteTest : CompleteTestBase() {
        
            @Rule
            @JvmField
            var activityRule = ActivityTestRule(getActivityType(), true, false)
    
            @get:Rule
            val composeTestRule = createComposeRule() // If I put this in comment the test will succeed. 
        
            @Test
            @Throws(Exception::class)
            fun testAddElement() {
              
            val intent = Intent(targetContext, FieldJobActivity::class.java)
                     activityRule.launchActivity(intent)
    
                   onView(withId(R.id. complete_btn)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed()))); // Failed here
      
// Test more compose views here...
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive this will work, but try to use the `.assertDoesNotExist()` instead of `(matches(not(isDisplayed()))`

I believe with compose with a Visible.Gone modifier it will actually not compose the component so it can not ID an element to determine if it is not displayed.